# What's the error in this code?(C - File Handling)

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, file-handling

What I want to do is to write n(taken from user) elements to a file.Then read the elements again to an array and sort them and again write them in another file.
Finally open that file and display its contents.
But the code seems not to work, all syntax, grammar etc is checked what's the error??

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct data
 {
 int a,ar[100];
 }e;


int main()
{ FILE *f1,*f2;


 int i,j,n,t;
 printf("\nEnter Array Size:");

 scanf("%d",&n);
 f1=fopen("Array.txt","w");
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 { printf("\nEnter %d element:",i+1);
   scanf("%d",&e.a);
   fprintf(f1,"%d",e.a);
 }
 fflush(stdin);
 fclose(f1);
 rewind(f1);
 i=0;
 f1=fopen("Array.txt","r");
 while((fscanf(f1,"%d",&e.ar[i++]))!=EOF)
 {}
 fclose(f1);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  { for(j=0;j<n-1;j++)
     {     if(e.ar[j]>e.ar[j+1])
             {  t=e.ar[j];
                e.ar[j]=e.ar[j+1];
                e.ar[j+1]=t;
             }
     }
  }


 f2=fopen("Sort.txt","w");
 i=0;
 while((fprintf(f2,"%d",e.ar[i]))!=EOF)

 { i++;}
 fclose(f2);
 f2=fopen("Sort.txt","r");
 while((fscanf(f2,"%d",&e.a))!=EOF)
  { printf("%d ",e.a);
  }
 fclose(f2);
 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried running and debugging it?

Comment: @SimonBosley Yes a lot of times. Sometimes it runs and prints garbage and other times just exits

Comment: So @Kunal when you're debugging it, which line does it go wrong and how?

Comment: @SimonBosley Actually, I had this on my practical examination today, and what I realized that the elements in the array( ar[]) are wrong. So the bubble sort is in vain and so is the rest of the code . So i think the part where I take value of element 'e' and write it in the file, and also when I read from the file to an array go wrong! But why and how??(I don't know!)

Comment: You think? Why not just run a debugger and step through the code line by line and see what's going on properly.

Comment: @SimonBosley I'm new to programming and I don't know much about debugging( I use Code Blocks) . Will you be kind enough to tell me?? or just point out the 'real' error!

Comment: For starters, check the result of fopen and make sure the files successfully opened. When writing to `Sort.txt` you should write the amount of elements in the array, not write until eof.

Comment: @user1320881 Yeah The file successfully opens( It's created in the directory) but it has some other values than which I enter !

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know the error? I found a HUGE one.

As I was running your program, I have determined a segmentation fault occurs after this line:

```
f2=fopen("Sort.txt","w");
```

The major error here is that you opened a file for writing data to it, but you're making a rather confusing loop.

This is your code:

```
 i=0;
 while((fprintf(f2,"%d",e.ar[i]))!=EOF)
 { i++;}
```

In the state it is in, the value of i will exceed the upper bound value of your ar int array. You set the upper bound value to 100, but in the while loop, it will run endlessly until segmentation fault happens (when i goes past 100) because fprintf will never return an EOF (according to what the linux manual on fprintf claims).

What I would suggest instead is this:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    fprintf(f2,"%d",e.ar[i]);
}
```

where n is the number of elements to finally print (as indicated by user at beginning of the program).